When I right click, the selected object disappears
I am pretty new to blender, so I don't know if this is intended or not. Lately, whenever I press right click, the object selected disappears or unlinks. This is pretty annoying since I want to box select some things, but every time it just unlinks the object. This bug is prevalent on all projects that I open, and it's very annoying. I am using blender 3.5, btw.

Perhaps one of the first things we could look for is a strange key-binding.  Header > Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Search by Key-Binding rmb . Anything funny in there?  Or .. You can save your preferences manually (Hamburger bottom-right) Switch off AutoSave just in case .. 'Load Factory Preferences' . If no joy, you can use the same menu to 'Revert'.
